# How to use sub-select query in Magento 1.x collection (Admin Grid)

Tags: magento-1.9, admin

I have created a MySQL query for Magento table.

```
SELECT account_id,
count(session_id) as sessions,

(SELECT count(event_code) from my_custom_table where event_code = 4 
group by account_id) as review_design,

(SELECT count(event_code) from my_custom_table where event_code = 5 
group by account_id) as pdf_created,

(SELECT count(event_code) from my_custom_table where event_code = 2 
group by account_id) as email_sent

FROM my_custom_table 
group by account_id;
```

I have tried changing this plain query to Magento convention for  `protected function _prepareCollection()` in admin grid. However, I am not able not to convert. I have gone through many answers on the internet, but most are related to the join query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I'm mistaken, I'm not sure the SQL you've got there will do what you've intended. From the looks of it, you want to select all the accounts in my_custom_table, with statistics for each one based on the data (also in my_custom_table) against each account.

The problem I see is the in each the subquery there is no join to account_id in the main SQL, which means for each account_id in your table, you'll get the total count of each event_code regardless of account_id (so all the rows counts will be the same)

A rewrite of the query would also make it much easier to "convert" to the standard magento mechanism, if the query was rewritten to be like this:

```
SELECT 
   main_table.account_id,
   COUNT(s.session_id) as sessions,
   COUNT(r.event_code) as review_design,
   COUNT(p.event_code) as pdf_created,
   COUNT(e.event_code) as email_sent
FROM 
  my_custom_table main_table
LEFT JOIN my_custom_table s ON main_table.account_id = s.account_id AND s.session_id != ''
LEFT JOIN my_custom_table r ON main_table.account_id = r.account_id AND r.event_code = 4
LEFT JOIN my_custom_table p ON main_table.account_id = p.account_id AND p.event_code = 5
LEFT JOIN my_custom_table e ON main_table.account_id = e.account_id AND e.event_code = 2
GROUP BY main_table.account_id;
```

Then you could then write code for a collection something like this (untested):

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('module/model')->getCollection();

$collection->getSelect()
           ->joinLeft(
               array('s' => 'my_custom_table'),
               'main_table.account_id = s.account_id AND s.session_id != ""',
               array('sessions' => 'COUNT(s.session_id)')
           )
           ->joinLeft(
               array('r' => 'my_custom_table'),
               'main_table.account_id = r.account_id AND r.event_code = 4',
               array('review_design' => 'COUNT(r.event_code)')
           )
           ->joinLeft(
               array('p' => 'my_custom_table'),
               'main_table.account_id = p.account_id AND p.event_code = 5',
               array('pdf_created' => 'COUNT(p.event_code)')
           )
           ->joinLeft(
               array('e' => 'my_custom_table'),
               'main_table.account_id = e.account_id AND e.event_code = 2',
               array('email_sent' => 'COUNT(e.event_code)')
           )
        ->group('main_table.account_id');
```

Which would give you the intended collection.